# Chat Solution for Mobile App

Tags: python-2.7, redis, chat, tornado, mobile-application

I am looking for a chat solution that I can integrate into my mobile app. So far, I have been looking into python solutions and have come across the "chat demo in tornado" library. Are there any more advanced solutions that I can look into ?

CHat demo link : https://github.com/facebook/tornado/tree/master/demos/chat

Answer (score 0):

There is this play2 (java) app that has been developed as an example by Heroku that makes use of Redis and WebSockets: https://github.com/heroku-examples/play-websockets-chat-sample

It could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots.

Some [django](https://github.com/heroku-examples/python-websockets-chat) based are:

- Using the excelent pusher.com service: https://github.com/andres-torres-marroquin/django-pusher-chat
- https://github.com/qubird/django-chatrooms
- uing comet: https://bitbucket.org/nicoechaniz/django-live/src
- with tornado and websockets: https://github.com/aruseni/chat
- https://github.com/sveetch/djangotribune
- http://code.google.com/p/django-chat/
- http://code.google.com/p/django-jqchat/

Some [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) based:

- using gevent and websockets: https://github.com/kcarnold/flask-gevent-socketio-chat
- using gevent and websockets running on heroku: http://callmephilip.github.io/chatzilla/
- using websockets on heroku: https://github.com/heroku-examples/python-websockets-chat

I'm pretty sure that there are chat apps for most of the python web frameworks we know. I've listed only those for django and flask because they are my favourite web frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I know  a chat software named 123 Flash Chat. I guess it will totally satisfied with your request. They provide mobile chat app integration for ios and andriod. You can have a try, hope it will help you. :)

http://www.123flashchat.com/mobile-chat-promo.html
http://www.123flashchat.com/build-mobile-chat-app

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an android (JAVA) chat library I recommend [MQTT chat](https://mqtt-chat.com). It is more than a library, a complete messenger with extremely fast messages dending  using the MQTT protocol and also it provides audio and video calls with webrtc. integration is also very easy. Even a beginner in Android can integrate it